# How to fix the error blob/text field cant have default value in Phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I was trying to add an field to the existing table its of type TEXT ,But i am getting an error text field cant have default values.please help me to the solve this issue.

Comment: That is a behaviour of mySQL, not phpMyAdmin. Why do you need to change it?

Comment: k, i thought it as phpmyadmin error

Answer (score 0):

When creating the new column do not set the TEXT field to have a default value.

I quote this line from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

```
BLOB and TEXT columns cannot have DEFAULT values.
```